# should redirect to not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

redirect_to is failing for me in my cucumber tests.  The step_definition method is

```
Then /^I should be redirected to "(.*)"$/ do |url|
  response.should redirect_to(url)
end
```

In Rails 2.3.3 I'm doing:

```
redirect_to some_url, :status => 301 and return false
```

I'm running that from the application_controller.rb and returning false.  When I tail the test.log I see it redirect yet the cucumber test still fails with a

```
expected redirect_to ..., got no redirect
```

The cucumber code looks like:

```
Given I go to "/blogs?page=1"
Then I should be redirected to "/blogs"
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: FYI returning false doesn't do anything anymore inside before_filters http://dev.rubyonrails.org/changeset/7984

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you just have to save_and_open_page. I find that any time cucumber is giving me trouble it's because of something like sessions and I open the resultant page to find a nasty flash error or something telling me exactly why I'm being an idiot this time. :)

Not implying that you're being an idiot, only I do that I think. At least that's what rspec seems to think of me most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change 'response.should redirect_to(url)' to 'response.should redirect_to(url, :status => 301)', other than that I can't see anything wrong.